# How to make a custom C++ class a QML Type?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I'm trying to push a simple struct, from C++, over to QML, but I can't seem to register it:

messages.h

```
#pragma once

#include <QString>
#include <QMetaType>

struct Ticket {
  Q_GADGET
  Q_PROPERTY(QString name MEMBER name)
  Q_PROPERTY(QString description MEMBER description)

  public:
  QString name;
  QString description;
};
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Ticket);
```

and I am making it available to QML:

main.cpp

```
#include <QtWidgets>

#include "MyWindow.h"
#include "messages.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  qmlRegisterType<Ticket>("myself", 1, 0, "Ticket");
  MyWindow the_window;
  the_window.show();

  return app.exec();
}
```

EDIT: including QML for reference

```
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.11
import QtQuick 2.11

RowLayout {
  id: layout
  property var tickets

  onTicketsChanged: {
    console.log("dum dum dum");
  }
}
```

When compiling, I get the following error:

```
/Users/myself/lib/Qt/5.11.2/clang_64/lib/QtQml.framework/Headers/qqmlprivate.h:101:24: error: only virtual member
      functions can be marked 'override'
        ~QQmlElement() override {
                       ^
/Users/myself/lib/Qt/5.11.2/clang_64/lib/QtQml.framework/Headers/qqmlprivate.h:107:50: note: in instantiation of
      template class 'QQmlPrivate::QQmlElement<Ticket>' requested here
    void createInto(void *memory) { new (memory) QQmlElement<T>; }
                                                 ^
/Users/myself/lib/Qt/5.11.2/clang_64/lib/QtQml.framework/Headers/qqml.h:292:33: note: in instantiation of function
      template specialization 'QQmlPrivate::createInto<Ticket>' requested here
        sizeof(T), QQmlPrivate::createInto<T>,
                                ^
/Users/myself/dev/my_project/src/MyWindow.cpp:69:3: note: in instantiation of function template specialization
      'qmlRegisterType<Ticket>' requested here
  qmlRegisterType<Ticket>("myself", 1, 0, "Ticket");
  ^
1 error generated.
```

Is there a way, to make the Ticket struct available in my QML, so that I can push values from C++ to QML?  Or, is there a way to find out what the `virtual member override` error means, in the context of qmlRegisterType?

Answer (score 2):

You can't with `Q_GADGETS`. You can make them known (`Q_DECLARE_METATYPE`), however you can't register them as QML type. Once they're known you can use them, but you can't create them on the QML side.

One way to work around this is for example having a helper class (singleton or context property) with a (static) member function returning an instance of your gadget.

---

If you want to be able to also create them you have to use `Q_OBJECT` macro and inherit from `QObject` instead (note `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` requires a pointer then).

Comment: Yes, if you are new to Qt go with QObject derived types for QML interaction, if you have nothing special to do and know why you really really want a Gadget and nothing else. Most of the time Gadgets are premature optimization. On the other hand there is nothing wrong with having a factory method on a QObject (I recommend a QJsValue constructor for the Gadget, hen the factory method can just forward it and initialize the object in one line)

Comment: Is there a way to push an QList/QVector of fielded values (each has name and desc) to QML, instead of class instances?  Such as with QVariant, or Q_GADGET?  I don't need to modify or create the values in QML, just push from C++ -> QML... all are immutable.

Comment: @ouni You can use your gadget. All you're missing is a `qRegisterMetaType<QVector<Ticket>>();` or list depending on what you want to use. Then you can expose that list or vector to QML via signals / slots / methods

Comment: I've registered the metatype, but when I do `my_widget->setProperty("tickets", shown_tickets)` it tells me that there is no conversion to QVariant.  Am I able to do it this way, or do I need to use signals/slots/methods?

Comment: @ouni try QVariant::fromValue(shown_tickets), if that doesn't work let me see if i can build an example